# x-editable / ng-tags-input / TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, ng-tags-input

I've got a problem with ng-tags-input (maybe the problem relies on the combination to x-editable and ui-router):

I have an application with three states: "main", "sub1" and "sub2". On each sub i have a x-editable tags-input like this:

```
<div editable-tags-input="model_content"
     data-e-form="(...)"
     data-e-ng-model="model_content"
     data-e-name="(...)"
     e-display-property="name"
     e-placeholder="(...)"
     e-replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
     e-add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
     name="(...)">
    <!-- advanced item display -->
    <a ng-click="showEdit()" 
       class="editable editable-click"
       ng-class="model_content.length === 0?'editable-empty':''">
        <span ng-repeat="a in model_content">
            {{a.name}}{{$last?'':', '}}
        </span>
        <span ng-if="model_content.length === 0">
            (empty)
        </span>
    </a>

    <editable-tags-input-auto-complete source="getItems()"
                                       min-length="1"
                                       load-on-focus="true"
                                       load-on-empty="true"
                                       max-results-to-show="20">

    </editable-tags-input-auto-complete>
</div>
```

This runs all fine - without any problems on one of the subs. If i click on the link (->showEdit()), the ng-tags-input is created/shown, the editable tags are created and the autocomplete is running fine.

**BUT** if i navigate to the main view and then to the other sub (eg from sub1 to main to sub2), the autocomplete is not working any more: After focusing the edit (and maybe entering any char), i get

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
        at ng-tags-input.js:623
        at processQueue (angular.js:16383)
        at angular.js:16399
        at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17682)
        at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17495)
        at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
        at angular.js:19621
        at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5964)
        at angular.js:6243(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13920(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10467processQueue @ angular.js:16391(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16399$eval @ angular.js:17682$digest @ angular.js:17495$apply @ angular.js:17790(anonymous function) @ angular.js:19621completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:5964(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6243
```

The method getItems() is not event called on the second sub-state.

Can anyone help?